# Chrome Extension: Unbind event listener added by script executed on the fly

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that will **bind** mousedown event listener on "body" when the **browser action is clicked**. And when the browser action is clicked again, it will **unbind** the mousedown event.

But for some reason, unbind is not working even though the logs say the codes executed. I have tried bind()/unbind() methods as well to no avail.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "View Font Info",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "f.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "f.png", tabId:tab.id});

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"jquery.js"}, function(){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "on.js"});
    });
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "", tabId:tab.id});

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"jquery.js"}, function(){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "off.js"});
    });
  }
});
```

**on.js (script to bind event)**

```
console.log("On");
$("body").on('mousedown.custom', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something...
});
```

**off.js (script to unbind event)**

```
console.log('off');
$("body").off('mousedown.custom');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the whole jQuery library on a mouse click seems redundant to me. It may also explain your problem (because you do it for both ON and OFF). Try to load & execute jQuery outside of the click event handler or at least make sure it doesn't run twice.

Also the way you're communicating with your content script is not ideal. You don't need different files just use [`message passing`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

**background.js**

```
var isjQueryLoaded = {};

function executeAfterjQuery(tabId, fn) {
    if (isjQueryLoaded[tabId]) {
      fn();
    } else {
      isjQueryLoaded[tabId] = true;
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file:"jquery.js" }, fn);
    }
}

var toggle = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  var path  = toggle ? "f.png" : "";
  var state = toggle ? "on" : "off";
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: path, tabId:tab.id });
  executeAfterjQuery(tab.id, function () {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { state: state });
  });
});
```

**script.js**

```
function on() {
  // ...
}

function off () {
  // ...
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    (message.state == "on") ? on() : off();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the response is very comprehensive. By the way, I had to change to chrome.tabs.sendMessage() to make it work.